# How to analyse device and os distribution based on total revenue in firebase analytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

Our iOS app has paid users, both who purchased on the app store directly or purchased an 
In-App-Purchase. The app is launched in multiple countries.

I am trying to analyse the app using firebase analytics. I want to know if I can analyse our 
users based on total revenue. To elaborate, I want to get breakdown of user device models,
OS version etc based on revenue in a common currency.
For example, if my total revenue is 10$(this includes purchases from multiple countries) and users who are
using iphone 7 paid 7$ in total and iphone 6 users paid 3$ in total I want the breakdown to
be 7:3(iphone 7 vs iphone 6).

Is there anyway to do this in firebase?

PS: If I have to just get the breakdown of number of paid users I can just create a custom
user property "paidUser" which will store a boolean value and then use it as filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Filter->UserProperty->Device Model on the Dashboard to filter the average revenue. For more granular filtering, I think Big Query will provide better data.

Comment: The average revenue that firebase console shows is the revenue through in_app_purchase event or ecommerce_purchase event. It doesn't track the purchase on the app store directly(This is to track our old users when the app was a paid app. Now its free to try out and then we prompt for IAP). Also because we already have users and we want to analyse them as well filtering with device model will not work. Suppose I log how much the user paid using a custom user property, can I get breakdown of devices based on total of this custom property in firebase? Is it possible in big query?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear of what the intention is. If you know the paid users, you can tag them with some values and try to filter both the model and the user property in big query since it is more flexible than the current dashboard. Note that the life-time revenue will not account for previous paid app values in this way unless you log an ecommerce-purchase for those users.

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you said. Suppose a user property is a number. Can I analyse device, os based on sum of values of this user property for all users? To be clear I will tag all users with some price which is the amount they paid us. If total of this user property is 100$ and through iPhone 7 we got 30$, 7+ we got 40$, iPhone 8 we got 30$, I would like the analysis like 3:4:3 (7 vs 7+ vs 8). I know this isn't possible through firebase. Is this possible in bigquery? If not I will use the idea you suggested i.e., Make a ecommerce_purchase with the desired price for old users.

Comment: I think it's possible. You should try it yourself. Another way to do it is using Audience with the User Property that you tag. For example, you can create a condition like "paid_value == $30" & "device_model=iPhone7" for example. Then you can see the number of users that satisfy such audience definition on Firebase dashboard. Then you can infer the total amount by num_users x paid_value. I hope it helps your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. :)